# Convert string to double: input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, string, winforms, exception, double

I am getting some values from my Arduino over the serial port. The data has the format:
`"value1,value2,value3\r"` as a `string`.

*Example*: `"4.5,550.0,0.02\r"`

I can recieve and separate the values but when I try to convert them to `double` I get the following exception

> "input string was not in a correct format"`.

```
double Battery = 0, Voltage = 0, Current = 0;

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
    string bv = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf(",") - 1);
    data = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(",") + 1);
    string v0 = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf(",") - 1);
    data = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(",") + 1);
    string i = data;

    double batteryVoltage = Convert.ToDouble(bv);
    double V0 = Convert.ToDouble(v0);
    double I = Convert.ToDouble(i);

    Battery = batteryVoltage;
    Voltage = V0;
    Current = I;

}
```

Comment: You've abused Substring quite a lot here, what is wrong with `string.Split(',')` and `TryParse`?

Comment: This code works with your sample data. Please, give data which causes error

Comment: Are you sure your input is `4.5,550.0,0.02\r` and not `4.5,550.0,0.02\\r`?

Comment: Clarify precisely which line the error occurs on, the value of the input string at that point, and the overall input string as per the previous comment.

Comment: @user2790895 can you give us value of `data` when you get exception?

Comment: removed my ans. as per feedback. be curious to know if you get to the bottom of it. seems like it should work based on the information you've provided + some testing I did in LinqPad

Comment: Since some people aren't aware of this - the sample data fails on certain regional settings, e.g. Polish uses "," as a decimal point and doesn't consider "4.5" a proper string to convert.

Comment: Exactly where are you getting error however your method will not fetch correct numbers ,and you variable `i` will fetch `0.02\r` which will be handled by `Convert.ToDouble` and you will get `0.02` as your `Current` value however other values will be wrong but i don't think you are getting error on this method as per your example .

Answer (score 13):

Two things are a problem here. First, the conversion may fail because of regional settings (invalid decimal point character), so use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` from `System.Globalization` namespace as an additional parameter. Second thing, you are cutting off one character from your substrings, so remove `-1`.

```
string data = "4.5,550.0,0.02\r";
string bv = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf(","));
data = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(",") + 1);
string v0 = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf(","));
data = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(",") + 1);
string i = data;

double batteryVoltage = Convert.ToDouble(bv, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double V0 = Convert.ToDouble(v0, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double I = Convert.ToDouble(i, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Good notice on cutting off last character. That probably will be the reason of error

Comment: Right, fixed my answer as it does mess with the conversion. Still, CultureInfo setting should be there if the user has a regional setting which doesn't recognize "." as a decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me with the provided example input. Can you elaborate on the exception?

Try specifying the CultureInfo in the conversion.

Also, you should use the `String.Split()` method:

```
string data = "4.5,550.0,0.02\r";
var strings = data.Split(',');
var doubles = strings.Select(s => Convert.ToDouble(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();

double batteryVoltage = doubles[0];
double V0 = doubles[1];
double I = doubles[2];
```

Comment: It should be a comment to question, not an answer to the reason of error

Comment: and it will also probably fail on `0.02\r`

Answer (score 0):

Possible the \r char is causing the issue. Try trimming it before processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to split your string

```
 string[] separotrs = { ",", "\r" };
 string[] result= aurdino.Split(separotrs, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

       double batteryVoltage = Convert.ToDouble(result[1]); //Sorry if order is incorrect:-)
       double v0 = Convert.ToDouble(result[0]);
       double I = Convert.ToDouble(result[2]);
```

One thing i do not get is where exactly are you getting error however your method will not fetch correct numbers(cutting off the last value) ,and you variable **i** (`Current`) will fetch `0.02\r` which will be handled by `Convert.ToDouble` and you will get `0.02` as your Current value however other values will be wrong but i don't think you are getting error on this method as per your example.

[image: See here]